# Avoid exposure of API key and client ID when using Google Classroom browser API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to use the Google Classroom Browser API. I referred to the page at https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js for the Quick Start for this API, but unfortunately it seems to expose my Client ID and API key in the script within the HTML.

Here's a link to the sample page provided by Google:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/browser-samples/blob/master/classroom/quickstart/index.html

The Client ID and API key are exposed on lines 34 and 35:

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';
```

Is there any way I can use the Google Classroom Browser API without exposing my Client ID and API key? If not, how can I secure them and prevent unauthorised usage by anyone else?

Comment: Why do you want to hide those keys? They are not something like a private key and exposing them does not lead any issue.

Comment: @Peekbyte Other people may use them and consume my request quota.

Comment: I wonder you should register the domain name in google dashboard and google will verify all requests origins.

Comment: @Peekbyte is correct here, you can configure the clientID and APIKey to be registered with your domain and then only requests from that domain will be allowed for that clientID and API Key.